# Understand the meaning of `$_`

Tags: bash

Could you explain the following sentences from Bash manual about `$_`, especially the parts in bold,  maybe with some examples?

1. > At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to
   >   invoke the shell or shell script being executed as **passed in the environment
   >   or argument list**.
2. > **Subsequently**, expands to the last argument to the previous
   >   command, after expansion.
3. > Also set to the full pathname **used to invoke each
   >   command executed** and **placed in the environment exported to that command**.
4. > When **checking mail**, this parameter holds the name of the mail file.

Comment: -1 question unclear & not thoroughly researched. What have you tried? Where did your expectations misalign with the text? Do you not honestly understand the word 'subsequently'? If a new user were to ask this same question I would have the same questions of them (despite my similar innate curiosity as to exactly how things work).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I agree it's not very clear.

## 1. At shell startup,

- **if the `_` variable was in the environment that `bash` received**, then `bash` leaves it untouched.

  In particular, if that `bash` shell was invoked by another `bash`
  shell (though `zsh`, `yash` and some `ksh` implementations also do
  it), then that `bash` shell will have set the `_` environment
  variable to the path of the command being executed (that's the 3rd
  point in your question). For instance, if `bash` is invoked to
  interpret a script as a result of another `bash` shell interpreting:

  ```
  bash-script some args
  ```

  That `bash` will have passed `_=/path/to/bash-scrip` in the
  environment given to `bash-script`, and that's what the initial
  value of the `$_` `bash` variable will be in the `bash` shell that
  interprets that script.

  ```
  $ env -i _=whatever bash -c 'echo "$_"'
  whatever
  ```
- Now, **if the invoking application doesn't pass a `_` environment
  variable**, the invoked `bash` shell will initialise `$_` to the `argv[0]` it receives
  itself which could be `bash`, or `/path/to/bash` or
  `/path/to/some-script` or anything else (in the example above, that
  would be `/bin/bash` if the she-bang of the script was `#! /bin/bash`
  or `/path/to/bash-script` [depending on the
  system](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#results)).

  So that text is misleading as it describes the behaviour of the
  caller which `bash` has no control over. The application that invoked
  `bash` may very well not set `$_` at all (in practice, only some
  shells and a few rare interactive applications do, `execlp()` doesn't
  for instance), or it could use it for something completely different
  (for instance `ksh93` sets it to `*pid*/path/to/command`).

  ```
  $ env bash -c 'echo "$_"'
  /usr/bin/env   (env did not set it to /bin/bash, so the value we
                 get is the one passed to env by my interactive shell)
  $ ksh93 -c 'bash -c "echo \$_"'
  *20042*/bin/bash
  ```

## 2. Subsequently

The *Subsequently* is not very clear either. In practice, that's as soon as `bash` interprets a *simple command* in the current shell environment.

- **In the case of an interactive shell**, that will be on the first simple command interpreted from `/etc/bash.bashrc` for instance.

  For instance, at the prompt of an interactive shell:

  ```
   $ echo "$_"
   ]      (the last arg of the last command from my ~/.bashrc)
   $ f() { echo test; }
   $ echo "$_"
   ]      (the command-line before had no simple command, so we get
           the last argument of that previous echo commandline)
   $ (: test)
   $ echo "$_"
   ]      (simple command, but in a sub-shell environment)
   $ : test
   $ echo "$_"
   test
  ```
- **For a non-interactive shell**, it would be the first command in `$BASH_ENV` or of the code fed to that shell if `$BASH_ENV` is not
  set.

## 3. When Bash executes a command

The third point is something different and is hinted in the discussion above.

`bash`, like a few other shells will pass a `_` environment variable to commands it executes that contains the path that `bash` used as the first argument to the `execve()` system calls.

```
$ env | grep '^_'
_=/usr/bin/env
```

## 4. When checking mail

The fourth point is described in more details in the description of the `MAILPATH` variable:

> 'MAILPATH'
>
> A colon-separated list of **filenames which the shell periodically
>        checks for new mail**.
>
> Each list entry can specify **the message that
>        is printed when new mail arrives in the mail file** by separating the
>        filename from the message with a '?'.
>    When used in the text of the
>        message, '$_' expands to the name of the current mail file.

Example:

```
$ MAILCHECK=1 MAILPATH='/tmp/a?New mail in <$_>' bash
bash$ echo test >> /tmp/a
New mail in </tmp/a>
```

Comment: Also this old chestnut: mkdir somedirectory && cd $_ puts you right in the directory you just created.

Answer (score 11):

Try this simple example:

```
echo "$_"
echo "test"
echo "$_"
```

Run it by giving the absolute path (`/home/$USERNAME/test.sh`); output:

```
/home/$USERNAME/test.sh
test
test
```

First `$_` contains the path you used to invoke the script and the second one contains the first argument to the middle `echo`.
For the third item in the list, if you start a new terminal and type echo `$_`
it will show the variable containing the `PATH` which is usually used to lookup and invoke commands (in my Ubuntu machine) in a normal shell or absolute path to your `.bashrs` file in a login shell.

For the item four from bash man page:

> When used in the text of the message, `$_` expands to the name of the
>   current mailfile.

Comment: Thanks. (1) can you explain the third case with examples? (2) When I open a new gnome terminal tab, the output of `echo $_` is `EDITOR`, and why is it? Which case does it follow? (3) Can you given an example of how to check mails, and of using `$_` in this case?

Comment: Open your `.bashrc` and comment out every line there. Keep only a single line containing a command like `echo "test"` or similar. Save and close. Then run `bash` and immediately `echo $_`. This last echo should print test in the output.

Comment: For the mail part I have not used Unix mail and don't have a working mail installed on my system now so cannot give you example. But should be obvious if you follow the description of `MAILPATH` in http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/bash1.html

Comment: FYI, the canonical, up-to-date version of the bash manual is: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html  . It's version 4.3 while the linuxcommand page was 4.1.

Answer (score 9):

For case 2, an example is worth a thousand words:

```
mkdir my_long_dir
cd $_
```

Does what you'd guess / hope for¹.  Gives me a simple placeholder when I'm on the command line to save me having to repeat myself.

---

<sup>¹ at least here for a such a simple directory name and assuming `$CDPATH` is empty or unset and `$IFS` has not been modified from its default value. In the general case, you'd need something like `mkdir -p -- $'-less tamed directory-/../foo/ *** Ah! *** /\n\n' && CDPATH= cd -P -- "$_"`, though that's orthogonal to this discussion.</sup>