# If there is no assignment of environment variable following `env`, what kind of environment is a command executed with?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, coreutils

`env` runs a command with a modified environment.

```
env [option]... [name=value]... [command [args]...]
```

If there is no `name=value` or option following `env`, what kind of environment is a command executed with?

What is the purpose of using `env` without any `name=value` or option following?

[For example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280557/674)

```
env bash -c 'echo "$_"'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not see this with `env bash -c 'set'`?

Comment: Do you mean see `bash: set: No such file or directory` after running `env bash -f 'set'`?

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: `set` display all the shell variables and functions. What is it to do with environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

The output of

```
env cat /proc/self/environ
```

suggests that the environment is unchanged if nothing else is given.

(Or indeed, if I had bothered to read the fine manual, 'If no COMMAND, print the resulting environment', so plain `env` will be just fine.)

Comment: Thanks. Then what is the difference between using `env` and not using `env`? What is the purpose of using `env` without any assignment following?

Comment: "no COMMAND" is indeed a totally different situation from no `name=value` and option

Comment: @Tim: you might find https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/3929 helpful. In a nutshell, it can make sure you call a binary, not an alias or function, without knowing where exactly it is (other than in `$PATH`).