# What can we use "mail" for?

Tags: bash, email

From Bash manual and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280557/674

> > 'MAILPATH'
> >
> > A colon-separated list of  filenames which the shell periodically
> >          checks for new mail .
> >
> > Each list entry can specify  the message that
> >          is printed when new mail arrives in the mail file  by separating the
> >          filename from the message with a '?'.  When used in the text of the
> >          message, '$_' expands to the name of the current mail file.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ MAILCHECK=1 MAILPATH='/tmp/a?New mail in <$_>' bash
> bash$ echo test >> /tmp/a
> New mail in </tmp/a>
> ```

"Mail" doesn't mean the same as emails or instant messages.
What does "mail" mean?

Does the content of a mail file consist of one or more than one "mails"?
If more than one, how are the mails separated from each other?

What event is considered as the arrival of a new mail?

Is "mail" a concept within a special application, the bash shell, or the OS?
There doesn't need a special application for handling (sending and receiving) "mails".
Rather the bash shell checks new "mails".

What can we use "mail" for?

- For communication between multiple users,
- for inter-processes communication like named pipes,
- for detecting changes to specific files (this is what I can tell from the example above)?

Thanks.

Comment: Mail _does_ mean the same as email.  This is for the case that your email is delivered to a file on your workstation.  A separate daemon would receive mail and write (append) it to a mail file.

Comment: I think you need to run `sendmail` for the `mail` command to work but it seems that you already have it running. You can use programs such as `mutt` to open `/tmp/a` `mbox`: `mutt -f /tmp/a`

Comment: In the Mbox format, each message begins with a line that starts with the word From and a space. This is how the messages are separated. (Note that a message typically also contains a line that begins with "From:", these lines do not separate messages.)

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thanks. What program do you use for receiving mail and writing (appending) it to a mail file, and what program  for reading the messages?

Answer (score 10):

It used to be more common for every internet-connected host to run its own smtp daemon to accept smtp connections (`tcp/25`, with no consideration of security) and deliver mail for local users to a file or directory either under their home directory, or in something like `/var/spool/mail/${USERNAME}` (or, alternately, to blindly relay it to another host if the mail was not addressed to a local user).  [Various formats](https://serverfault.com/questions/564456/maildir-vs-mbox-what-are-the-practical-differences) were used, but frequently the format was simply the raw mail (including all headers followed by the message body) concatenated in one long file.

The `MAILPATH` bash variable indicates the location of the mail file as configured in your local smtp daemon.  Compare [`biff`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=biff&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%205.0-RELEASE) utility.

Comment: Thanks. Does bash provide some commands for us to send, receive and read mails?

Comment: @Tim, that is more of a separate question.  There have been numerous terminal-based mail clients (assuming that's what you mean by "Does `bash` provide..."), including the basic and appropriately named `mail`.

Comment: The bash manual mentions mails, so I assume bash provide mail support to some degree, but I am not sure what kind of support bash provides to mails. From your comment, I was wondering if bash just provide a server for mails, and not clients for mails?

Comment: Thanks. I know this has been a while.In "It used to be more common for every internet-connected host to run its own smtp daemon to accept smtp connections (tcp/25, with no consideration of security) and deliver mail for local users", is the "smtp daemon" a MDA?

Comment: Does bash take the role of a MUA, via its MAILPATH variable?